# sub-query com parâmetro da query principal

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Tenho esta query:

```sql
SELECT 
id_arquivo, nome_arquivo, etapa, em_uso, em_uso_por, processo_concluido, obs_temp_etapa_atual, cod_funcionario_dev,  status_devolucao, devolvido_por, SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_arquivo, " ", 1) as referencia, COUNT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_arquivo, " ", 1)) as QTD_DISP
FROM producao  

WHERE
cod_trabalho = '458' and 
etapa = '33' and 
tipo_arquivo = 'Still' and 
processo_concluido < 1 and 
em_uso < 1 and 
(cod_funcionario_dev IS NULL or cod_funcionario_dev = '1') 

GROUP BY referencia
```

Eu já tenho um campo que "conta" a quantidade disponível na ETAPA atual.
Eu preciso agora contar QUANTOS ESTÃO NAS ETAPAS ANTERIORES, e só exibir os registros se não houverem registros nas etapas anteriores.

Seria algo como adicionar ao SQL acima:

```sql
HAVING

COUNT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_arquivo, " ", 1)) = (
    SELECT   
COUNT(cod_cliente)
FROM producao  

WHERE  cod_trabalho = '458' and 
etapa <= '33' and 
tipo_arquivo = 'Still' and 
processo_concluido < 1 and 
em_uso < 1 and 
(cod_funcionario_dev IS NULL or cod_funcionario_dev = '1') AND
SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_arquivo, " ", 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_arquivo, " ", 1)

GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_arquivo, " ", 1))
```

Me parece que o problema está em passar a função agregada relacionada ao "nome_arquivo". Se eu arbitrar ali o nome, funciona (porque retorna apenas 1 registro). Mas eu preciso que ela faça a consulta pra cada registro, considerando o valor retornado da query principal.

Acredito que se conseguir uma forma de passar uma função agregada, vinda da query principal, para a sub-query, resolvo meu problema.

Eu tenho registros como por exemplo (simplificando):

```sql
NOME_ARQUIVO    ETAPA
REF1 V1          3
REF1 V2          3
REF1 V2          4
REF2 V1          4
REF2 V2          4
```

Supomos que a etapa atual seja "4", com os dados acima eu quero exibir apenas a REF2.

A REF1, como tem 1 registro na etapa 4, mas 2 na etapa 3, não deve ser retornado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Penso que é isto que precisas, tens de fazer uma subquery para juntar o atual com o anterior, assim:

```
        select *
from (SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(NomeArquivo, ' ', 1) as NomeArquivo, max(etapa) as etapaAtual
FROM producao  
group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(NomeArquivo, ' ', 1) 
) as ProdAtual

 left outer join (
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(NomeArquivo, ' ', 1) as NomeArqAnterior, min(etapa) as EtapaAnterior
from producao
group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(NomeArquivo, ' ', 1)) as ProdAnterior on ProdAtual.NomeArquivo=ProdAnterior.NomeArqAnterior and ProdAtual.etapaAtual>ProdAnterior.EtapaAnterior
where ProdAnterior.EtapaAnterior is null
```

Só obtens o registo com REF2.

Comment: Oi Ricardo, agradeço a força, mas não funcionou como preciso. Pra rodar, tive de tirar o "producao" em: ProdAnterior.nomeArquivo=producao.SUBSTRING_INDEX(nome_arquivo, " ", 1)

E o que preciso de fato é que ele compare todos os registros que tem ETAPA com código igual ou inferior ao da etapa atual (no caso o 33).

Aí caso eu TENHA arquivos com etapa anterior, não quero listar registro algum, apenas quando:

Registros etapa anterior = 0

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta pra ver se consigo explicar melhor o que preciso.

Comment: Ricardo, adicionei no final da pergunta as informações do formato dos registros. Ver se ajuda a clarear o que estou precisando

Comment: o exemplo de dados ajuda, vou alterar a query,,

Comment: Oi Ricardo bom dia! Obrigado pela força, resolvido!!! Abraço e boa semana! :-)